JFrame en Java Swing me muestra un diseño diferente al ejecutar el jar, que cuando presiono el botón Preview Design utilizando Grid Bag Layout
Buen día,
estoy utilizando Grid Bag Layout para centrar todos los componentes en un JFrame y al presionar el botón Preview Design el diseño es como yo lo deseo, pero luego genero el jar con un Clean and Build desde el IDE Netbeans y al ejecutar el jar, el diseño aparece diferente. Le anexo imagenes de las pruebas, espero poder resolverlo con su valiosa ayuda.
codigo:
private void initComponents() {
    java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

    btnEmiMoto = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnEmiCarro = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lblUser = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblPuesto = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblUbicacion = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("EMISION DE TICKET");
    getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    btnEmiMoto.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(154, 206, 91));
    btnEmiMoto.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    btnEmiMoto.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/sv/com/sertracen/images/moto2.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnEmiMoto.setText("Moto");
    btnEmiMoto.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnEmiMotoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
    gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 3;
    gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 8;
    gridBagConstraints.ipady = 19;
    gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
    gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(41, 83, 41, 0);
    getContentPane().add(btnEmiMoto, gridBagConstraints);

    btnEmiCarro.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(154, 206, 91));
    btnEmiCarro.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    btnEmiCarro.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/sv/com/sertracen/images/carro1.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnEmiCarro.setText("Carro");
    btnEmiCarro.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnEmiCarroActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
    gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
    gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 8;
    gridBagConstraints.ipady = 19;
    gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
    gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(41, 0, 41, 83);
    getContentPane().add(btnEmiCarro, gridBagConstraints);

    pack();
}




Ya que hablas de netbeans, agrega tu archivo form para poder verificar como te lo genera, ya que sin ello solamente podremos adivinar

Listo agregue las imagenes de ejemplo
